# App to answer mobile

Tags: android, osx

I'm looking for an app that runs in OSX that I can use to answer my mobile. There are apps like "[Telephone](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/telephone/id406825478?mt=12)" that you can use to answer your phone (not mobile).

**Requirements:**

- Runs in OSX
- Works with the Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android)
- Without monthly payment (It can have a one-off cost, but not a monthly payment for the main function of answering calls)

**Optional:**

- Works with iOS
- Make calls using your mobile without extra tariffs (only the tariffs that you would normally pay)

Comment: For iOS, with the upcoming release of OS X 10.10 Yosemite and iOS 8, you'll be able to use the new Continuity features to answer your iPhone from your Mac. But of course that won't work with Android, which is your main requirement.